# Include one widget instead of excluding all others

Tags: ejs, hexo

I have a couple of widgets in the sidebar.
I do not want that some of these widgets show on some of my pages.

I do not know how to write it more simple than this? I have many exclusions, so writing it like this would be a book-work full of lines.
I just want to write as simple as "on this page include only this or these widgets" (instead of "on this page exclude this and these widgets").

`<%if( !(page.layout=="alpha" && (name=="w1" || name=="w2" || name=="links" || name=="w3") ) &&
!(page.layout=="beta" && (name=="w400" || name=="w500" || name=="w600") ) ){
%>`

So question is how to make it simple that page "alpha" shows only widget895 for example?

Comment: Can you please fix the tags? It looks like only the EJS tag is actually relevant to this question.

Comment: @skirtle - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed that you've got some sort of loop over the widgets and that `name` corresponds to the current widget name within that loop.

```
<%
    var pageWidgets = {
        alpha: ['widget895'],
        beta: ['widget900', 'widget123']
    };

    var allowedWidgets = pageWidgets[page.layout];

    // Loop over the widgets and grab the name, I assume
    // you're already doing something similar.
    widgets.forEach(function(widget) {
        var name = widget.name;

        // This is the equivalent of the 'if' in your
        // original code. Note that I've allowed all
        // widgets by default.
        if (!allowedWidgets || allowedWidgets.includes(name)) {
            %>
            ...widget rendering here...
            <%
        }
    });
%>
```

Comment: about the loop thats correct - about allowing all widgets by default, i have problems understanding this. can you please show me how just one widget "w-12" (out of three, "w43", "w89", "w75"), would only show for "page-layout=alpha"?

Comment: @raulbaros My example should do what your original question asks: it just shows `widget895` for page layout `alpha`. Changing it to `w-12` just needs you to change `widget895` to `w-12`. When I say 'by default' I mean that for any layout not listed in `pageWidgets` the value of `allowedWidgets` will be `undefined`, so the `!allowedWidgets` check will allow all widgets. Changing it to `if (allowedWidgets &&` would disallow them all by default. Alternatively you could set a specific array of widgets as the default. Remember everything in the `<% %>` is just JavaScript, not special EJS syntax.